# Configure Swashbuckle/SwaggerUI to present login page and include returned cookie in API requests

Tags: .net, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I've got a login page that sets a cookie on a successful response which can be included in API requests to authenticate a user. Both the login page and API are on the same domain.

Is it possible to configure Swashbuckle/SwaggerUI to prompt you to log in before accessing an endpoint and then include a cookie that was set from the login in the API requests (via Try it out!)?

Comment: Is this what you are asking: https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/cookie-authentication/  `Cookie authentication is currently not supported for "try it out" requests due to browser security restrictions.`

Comment: So I read that and should have included it in the post but wasn't 100% sure that it included my scenario. I was thinking that because the auth cookie is set from the same domain that the API resides on then the browser would be able to automatically include the cookie with the API requests. And not be impacted by the security restrictions associated with setting cookies manually for some other domain. Do you have any further insights into that thought @HelderSepulveda?